# Getting error while running spot bugs "A failure occurred while executing com.github.spotbugs.snom.internal.SpotBugsRunnerForWorker$SpotBugsExecutor"

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, spotbugs

Getting error while running spot bugs "A failure occurred while executing com.github.spotbugs.snom.internal.SpotBugsRunnerForWorker$SpotBugsExecutor"

Gradle Version :- 6.6.1
SpotBug plugin- 4.2

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'io.quarkus'
    id "com.github.spotbugs" version "4.2.0"

}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/main/resources'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.11"
    compile "org.jboss.logmanager:log4j2-jboss-logmanager"
    compile 'org.jboss.slf4j:slf4j-jboss-logging'
    compile 'org.jboss.logging:commons-logging-jboss-logging'


    spotbugsPlugins 'com.h3xstream.findsecbugs:findsecbugs-plugin:1.10.1'

}

compileJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    options.compilerArgs << '-parameters'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}


spotbugs {
    toolVersion = '4.2.0'
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem with Java 17

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the java version installed is `java 11`. You can check with `java -version` in the terminal.
Got the same error while using `java 18` to build a `java 11` project.